# SQL 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" When creating a table

Tags: oracle

When I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Movie_list" (
  "Movie_id"             NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  "Company"              VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  "Rating"               DECIMAL(5,1) NOT NULL,
  "Storyline"            VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  "Award_id"             VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  "Cast_and_Crew_id"     VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Movie_pk PRIMARY KEY (Movie_id),
  );
```

An Error report is producded -

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I don't see any problem, please help.

Comment: Pleas RTFM! You have not to wrap table and cols names between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Errors:

- Table and column names enclosed in quotes
- NUMBER and VARCHAR2 are not a valid mysql type
- A , is at the end of the constraint specification which is invalid

Comment: I'm running it in Oracle SQL developer,

Comment: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Then use the oracle tag

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your primary key specification, which reads

```
CONSTRAINT Movie_pk PRIMARY KEY (Movie_id),
```

However, in the table definition you've quoted the name of this field, i.e.

```
"Movie_id"             NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
```

Because the name of this field (and in fact every field in the table, and the name of the table itself) is quoted the names are stored by the database as the specified mixed-case name, and because Oracle converts all **unquoted** identifiers to UPPER_CASE it means that EVERY TIME YOU REFER TO THIS TABLE AND ITS FIELDS, YOU **MUST** QUOTE THEM. So your constraint should be

```
CONSTRAINT Movie_pk PRIMARY KEY ("Movie_id")
```

My recommendation is that you dispense with the quoted "Mixed_case" names. Get rid of the quotes and Oracle will store the names in UPPER_CASE internally. You can still *refer to them using Mixed_Case* if you want to but you won't have to "Quote_Them_Every_Time_You_Use_Them", which gets really old and reads very badly. I suggest you change you table definition to

```
CREATE TABLE Movie_list (
  Movie_id             NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  Company              VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  Rating               DECIMAL(5,1) NOT NULL,
  Storyline            VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  Award_id             VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  Cast_and_Crew_id     VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Movie_pk PRIMARY KEY (Movie_id)
  );
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me when I was trying to use some sort of keyword as a column name.
I tried to create a table with a column name of "uid" (without "" evidently), and i was getting this error:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Changing the column's name solved the error.